# Maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules of full support, over non-artinian local Cohen-Macaulay rings, are faithful?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, localization, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local Cohen-Macaulay ring of positive dimension. Let $M$ be a finitely generated maximal Cohen-Macaulay module i.e. $\operatorname{depth} M=\dim R$.
If $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, then is it true that $M$ is faithful?

My thoughts: Since $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, so the radical of the annihilator ann$_R(M)$ is exactly the nilradical of $R$, so every element in the annihilator of $M$ is nilpotent. We would be done if $R$ were reduced, but that's not necessarily the case.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=K[X,Y]/(X^2Y)$ and $M=R/(xy)$. Then $M$ is MCM, $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)=(xy)$, and $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ since every prime ideal of $R$ contains $x$ or $y$.

Comment: I just noticed that you want $R$ local. Then localize at $(x,y)$ or replace $K[X,Y]$ by $K[[X,Y]]$.

Comment: As a note, one can also take any proper cyclic module over an Artinian local ring; examples abound.